# Use of current_user setter in Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm a little confused here. In **chapter 8** of the fabulous [**Ruby on Rails Tutorial**](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-sign_in_success_not_yet_working) by *Michael Hartl*, I can't figure out why Michael uses a setter to set the instance variable `@current_user` to `user`.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
end
```

Why did he not just skip the setter method and do it this way instead?

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    @current_user = user
  end
end
```

Is it just because it's best practice to implement a setter or I don't get something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an OO question. Because the `current_user=` is part of the session's contract with the world. It is promising that, no matter where the user is ultimately stored (such as in `User.current_user`), you can always set it thru that interface.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read it, but he could be

- Making a point
- Following best practice
- Intending to use the setter elsewhere, earlier or later in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure he reuses that method later when the user loads another page. Something like:

```
# in application_controller
before_filter :authenticate

private
def authenticate
  if cookies[:remember_token]
    self.current_user = User.authenticate(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end

# in user.rb
def self.authenticate(token)
  find_by_remember_token(User.encrypt(token))
end
```